# How do you use ScalaMock with ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I tried the following

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalamock._
import org.scalamock.scalatest._

class TestMock extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with ShouldMatchers {
  "foo" should "bar" in {
    val obj = mock[Object]
    //...
  }
}
```

and the compiler tells me that the self type of `TestMock` does not conform to that of `MockFactory`. So I changed the class to

```
class TestMock extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with ShouldMatchers {
  self : MockFactory with Suite =>
  "foo" should "bar" in {
    val obj = mock[Object]
    //...
  }
}
```

and now it complains that `mock` is not a value.

I'm using scalatest_2.10-2.0.M5b.jar and scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10-3.0.1.jar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it: apparently one needs both the `scalamock-core` and `scalamock-scalatest-support` jars. I was assuming it was either one or the other.